# Routing a power trace through an IC pin

Tags: pcb-design

Is there anything inherently wrong with routing a power trace, which is used to pull up logic pins on an IC, through a pin of that same IC? Please see the example below -- the trace in question is "3.3v"

[image: Layout]

Comment: I don't think so unless there is something specific about your circuit. Power planes are kind of the same thing.

Comment: make sure you have close low ESR decoupling caps. and stay away from analog ground with tunnelling effects during flash.